TypeError: Type {} is not assignable to type string | undefined when importing an image in React
I'm using an image in my React component, and although it displays correctly, I keep seeing this warning:
TypeError: Type {} is not assignable to type string | undefined
Here’s my code:
import profilePic from './assets/profile.jpeg';

function Card() {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <img src={profilePic} alt="profile picture" />
            <h2>Profile Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, reiciendis.</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;

I'm using JavaScript in a React project, and profile.jpeg is located in the assets folder.
I also tried using require instead of import:
const profilePic = require('./assets/profile.jpeg');
But it didn’t resolve the warning.  Any suggestions on correctly managing this image import to avoid the warning?

You're trying to import an image using require, which is used for importing modules, the value of profilePic is {}. Pass the string that represents the path to the image instead

@LãNgọcHải It's a non-standard but incredibly popular practice for bundlers to provide a string path when importing non-JS assets like this. This user is almost certainly using tooling that supports it.

@rschristian thanks for correcting. For some reason I forgot about it at the moment, my bad.

There are two ways to fix this. Check the solutions below:

Type assertion with as keyword.
<img src={profilePic as string} alt="profile picture" />





Create a type declaration file.

In src folder, create a file with a name ending with .d.ts. For example file name images.d.ts and write the declaration as below:
// src/images.d.ts
declare module '*.jpeg' {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}

This solution will work for all the jpeg file imports.
